# Attempted to install Catalina in Target Disk Mode.... bricked my mac?

Tags: macos, mac

Ok so I may have bricked one of my MacBook Airs.

I am writing this post from the MB that's working. I have another one with a dead display. I connected them by Thunderbolt and mounted the broken one as a disk onto the working one using Target Disk mode. Then I used the disk utility to reformat the drive as APFS, Guid Partition. Then I tried to install Catalina but it says "You may not install to this volume because it's a Mac in target disk mode" (see screenshot.)

Have I created an irrecoverable situation?

The only solution I can imagine is to remove the HDD from the bum Mac, put it into the working Mac, install Catalina that way, then put the drive back. Both Macs are out of warranty so it's whatever... but I'm wondering there's a less messy way to get myself out of this hairy situation?

Comment: Keep in mind that it's not enough to get Catalina onto the MBA's disk, it probably also needs firmware updates. These are normally done by the installer, but can only be done when the installer runs *on the MBA itself*.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget you can connect an external display to the broken one.

Connect an external display to the broken one and use Internet Recovery (boot with Cmd-Opt-R held down) to reinstall the OS on the internal drive. Or boot it from a working macOS install on an external drive (even your working MBA in Target Disk Mode). There are also ways to create a bootable macOS installer image on an external drive such as a USB flash drive.